# How to do a SQL Query with vba from visio to a excel workbook?

Tags: excel, vba, visio

I'm trying to execute a sql query from visio using vba. My code runs and compiles but it doesn't give me any results. I established a connection to the workbook that have all the worksheets I need to query.  Here is the part of the code that goes thru the worksheets. Thanks

```
Dim WS_Count As Integer
    Dim I As Integer
        WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
           For I = 1 To WS_Count
               Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = "select * from ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets where ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Name = VLANs and VLAN = 2"

            Debug.Print strSQL
    Next I
            ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

I need to be able to query all worksheets on specific columns I have to query different columns on one worksheet I might have to make a query based on the vlan column and on the other one the query might be based on the ip column. My code compiles and gives no errors.

Comment: To use SQL against a workbook you will need to connect using the [ADODB library](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/168336/how-to-open-ado-connection-and-recordset-objects) with an ODBC [connection string](https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/)

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but it only allowed to connect to a single worksheet so I used a variable as object and was successful connecting to the entire workbook to test it I used the for to auto generate boxes with the name of each worksheet. So I'm connected but dont know how to get the data from the different worksheets. Can you provide me with an example of doing it with odbc I tried but I wasn't able to connect to the entire workbook I could only access one worksheet. Again thanks

Comment: Well, Google is your friend to find tutorials: eg https://excel-macro.tutorialhorizon.com/vba-excel-read-excel-workbook-as-database-using-odbc-source/. • Note that we cannot help you if you don't show how you have tried it.

Comment: Thanks. I been working on it using other method. I think I'm getting close to a solution. This is how part of the code looks like. WhatToFind = Array("meade", "gordon", "boston", "chesire")

Set rngToSearch = Range("A:A").Find(WhatToFind, , xlValues, xlPart)

For Each NetWrksht In NetWorkbook.Worksheets

    If Not rngToSearch Is Nothing Then

        Set vsoShape = Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Drop(Application.DefaultRectangleDataObject, aoffset, boffset)
        vsoShape.Text = rngToSearch.Cells